# Django: Building user Models with multiple relations. User -> Seller -> Buyer and User -> Buyer

Tags: django, django-authentication, geodjango

I'm trying to create the following structure: I have `Sellers` and `Buyers`, both of which are `Users` of my website. I would like a person to be able to search for Sellers and based on user location, I show the closest `Sellers`.

I'm using the default Django `User` auth, and I can only see `username` and `password` fields. I would also like to save `Seller` name. Should I add it to the `Seller` model, or somehow incorporate in into `User` model? I've looked at a few apps such as [Django Profiles](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/wiki/Home) and I'd like to figure out if it's the best way to go about it.

For this, I created a new app `users` and created a model for the Sellers in the `/users/models.py`

```
class Seller(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Buyer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller)
```

Currently I can display the Sellers, but I don't have access to their name or their user id. Should I simply store their name and last name in the Seller model or should I use an Authentication app? Also, there is no `__str__(self)` method, since I don't have a sensible identifier such as Name.

I could add fir names to both seller and buyer but then, if a Buyer becomes a Seller, it will have 2 sets of names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `OneToOneField`:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='buyer')
```

Then you can use `user.buyer` or `user.seller` to access the details. You should also check if they have a buyer or seller profile.

Comment: So where should I store the names? Django default User doesn't have them. Should I look into authentication apps which might have user profiles?  Or simply add the names to buyers and sellers?

Comment: @Roma you could add them to the `buyer` and `seller` or, better yet, make an intermediary `profile` with the common extra data.

Comment: And if you suggest using an authentication app, could you also name it please.

Comment: I see, so that basically covers the User Profile apps, available on Django packages. All info such as names, city location etc. goes there, and then I will have a Seller model, which will have multiple OnetoOne keys (to User Profile and User)

Comment: @Roma exactly. I wouldn't go for a 3rd party app unless you really need to.